# Router outlet inside primary router-outlet with relative path only

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I am looking for a solution for the below,

[image: router-outlet structure]

For example, i have an admin module with its own routing. however the admin module is loaded inside the primary router-outlet.

- **What i know i can do with using outlets, but not happy with the url**

www.website.com/admin(admin: usermanagement)

- **what i do want to**

www.website.com/admin/usermanagement

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That should be fine, just define `usermanagement` as a child route of `admin`

Comment: I want to load user management in secondary router-outlet, how can i do that?

Comment: Create a separate `<router-outlet>` inside the `admin` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You route config should go something like this

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, children: [
    { path: 'usermanagement', component: UserManagementComponent },
  ]}
];
```

Your primary `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will be inside the root component(AppComponent). This `router-outlet` will be responsible for loading the template of the `admin` route when it is reached. You might also want to add an empty route as a Child Component to that when the user navigates to just `/admin` the user is able to see something inside the secondary `router-outlet`.

Your secondary `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will be inside the `AdminComponent`'s template and will be responsible for rendering the UserManagementComponent.

Comment: Glad I helped! Happy Jamming!

Comment: when i am navigating via .ts file with  this._route.navigate(['usermanagement']) to set a default component. it doesn't detect the usermanagement. can you help

Comment: I think you'll have to navigate to using using:

`this._route.navigate(['/admin/usermanagement'])`

Consider marking this as an answer if this fixed your issue.

Comment: I actually created a new question for that and later i found the solution on my own. you can have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123600/angular-routes-set-default-component-for-router-outlet-when-loading-new-module?noredirect=1#comment91199832_52123600