# How to set featured module default landing component via router in angular 2

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I have two modules (clientModule, AdminModule), the admin module is lazy loaded.

On page load, the client module loads.

**Client module routes**

```
const _routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id', component: appComponent, children: [
      { path: 'page1', component: page1Component},
      { path: 'admin', loadChildren:  './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' }
    ]
  }
];
```

**Admin module routes**

```
const _routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AdminComponent, children: [
      { path: 'adminPage1', component: adminPage1Component},
      { path: 'adminPage2', component: adminPage2Component},

    ]
  }

];
```

Problems

1. The requirement is to navigate to 'adminPage1Component' component on Admin module load.

Comment: 1. Add { path: '', redirectTo: 'adminPage1 ', pathMatch: 'full' } in children. 2. Can you explain it more explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, if anyone having the same issue, the below way worked.

**Admin module route configuration**

```
const _routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AdminComponent, children: [
      { path: ' ', component: adminPage1Component},
      { path: 'adminPage1', component: adminPage1Component},
      { path: 'adminPage2', component: adminPage2Component},

    ]
  }
];
```

by adding a empty path ( **{ path: ' ', component: adminPage1Component}** ) inside the children array loaded the component by default.

further, if you an have element which need to add in a css class when the component is loaded. ex:

```
 <li routerLink="adminPage1" routerLinkActive="active">
          Admin Page 1
 </li>
```

you can do the below to support routerLinkActive

```
const _routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AdminComponent, children: [
      { path: ' ', component: adminPage1Component, redirectTo: 'adminPage1',  pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'adminPage1', component: adminPage1Component},
      { path: 'adminPage2', component: adminPage2Component},

    ]
  }
];
```

I basically added "**redirectTo: 'adminPage1',  pathMatch: 'full'**" to the empty path.